# How to check if path is valid in boost::filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost

I am setting a `boost::filesystem::path` from an edit field.  I notice that the constructor is happy to accept invalid characters for the filename.

How can I use `boost::filesystem` to check if the `boost::filesystem::path` object represents a valid filename?

Comment: Definition of "valid filename"?

Comment: I was hoping `boost::filesystem` would answer that question for me in a reasonable default fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/portability_guide.htm

This describes various functions for checking whether filenames are valid or not.

Comment: You could maybe use www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/portability_guide.htm as the link, since that will point to the current release.

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  Got to love that `windows_name()` returns `true` if an asterisk character is included in the string, even though the asterisk is not a valid character for a Windows file name.  That seems to be a bug.

Comment: For others: you must also first retrieve just the filename portion via `filename()`.

Comment: If you are using wide string for path you have to convert to multibyte string yourself? They don't seem to have wstring versions.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question - I had the same question, and I don't understand how to use the information on the linked page to answer the question.