# Is there a function that can tell me, given a string whether it is a legal directory name?

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if path is valid in boost::filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426671/how-to-check-if-path-is-valid-in-boostfilesystem)

Is there a function in std, boost::filesystem or any other cross-platform library that can tell me, given a `string` whether it is a legal directory path(even just syntactically, meaning it doesn't have to check if there is already a file or folder with that name)  but without creating the directory and deleting it in order to check.
In pseudo code:

```
string s[4];
s[0] = "C:\\foo";//<---valid
s[1] = "C:\\f*o";//<---invalid
s[2] = "foo\\bar";//<---valid
s[3] = "foo\\b*r";//<---invalid

for(int i=0;i < 4;i++){
    cout << is_valid_dir_name(s[i]) << " ";
}
//desired output in Windows: 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: `boost::filesystem::is_directory`

Comment: Unless you escape those backslashes, none of those are valid Windows directory names.

Comment: you have been trapped by the escape sequences pitfall

Comment: @Rob: Thanks, corrected the missing backslashes

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10426671/167251